# Extract from string and print a word

Tags: python, string, list, input

I've started learning Python a few weeks ago and I started typing some code. I have  a problem and I can't find any solution online (or I don't know how to search):

I input a numeric string of 13 digits: 01234**56**789ABC

From this string I have to extract let's say digits **56** and print a city designated for 56. At first it may not sound very difficult, but the problem is that I have a series of over 40 two digits codes + cities.

Can anyone help me with an advice, please?
Many thanks.

Comment: Are the numbers you need _always_ at indexes `5` and `6`?

Answer (score 0):

You can access any substring using the indexing operator []:

```
input_str = "0123456789ABC"
digits = input_str[5:7]
print(digits) # "56"
```

If you dont know the offset in advance, you can use the `find` string method to obtain the offset to the first appearance of a search string:

```
offset = input_str.find('56')
digits = input_str[offset:offset+2]
print(digits) # "56"
```

To search for *patterns*, check out the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module.

The second part of your question requires a bit more input from your side - if you have a mapping like this:

```
cities = {
    56: "foocity",
    99: "barcity",
    # ...
}
```

You can use a simple map lookup:

```
cities = {
    56: "foocity",
    99: "barcity",
    # ...
}

city_name = cities[int(digits)]
print(city_name) # "foocity"
```

Note the `int` conversion - in my example, the keys are of type int. Use whatever format and types suites your data set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to set keys as the city code and value as the city name, extract the code from the input string using string slicing and use it as key for the dictionary:

```
s = "0123456789ABC"
code = s[5:7]
code_city = {'56':'MyCity', '48':'CityX', '75':'CityY'}
print(code_city[code])
```

**Output**

```
MyCity
```